# Eclipse; Disable validation for swagger.yml

Tags: eclipse, gradle, yaml, swagger, warnings

I have a Java project built with Gradle, which I have imported into Eclipse using Spring's Gradle STS.

One file at the root of the project is `swagger.yml`, for which Eclipse is reporting dozens of errors, hundreds of warnings; for example:

- `Failed to match exactly one schema`
- `Invalid Reference Syntax - The referenced path or URI may contain invalid characters.`
- `object has missing required properties "swagger"`
- `object has properties "requestBody" which are not allowed`

Right now I just was want to disable these reports, as they are noise which drown out the Java and other errors which I'm interested in.

I can't find anything under Eclipse project properties which will do this. I've looked under:

- `Properties->Resource`
- `Properties->Builders`
- `Properties->Gradle`
- `Properties->Build Path`
- `Properties->Validation`
- `Properties->Spring->Spring YAML Editor` looked promising, but did not have any effect

Other `.yml` files in the project are not showing errors, for example, there's an `application.yml` and `bootstrap.yml` file under `src/main/resources`; they are both error-free.

My guess is that this is some issue at the cross-over between Swagger, Gradle and Eclipse.

How can I switch off these errors and warnings?

---

```
$ grep -i swagger build.gradle
    compile "io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.7.0"
    compile "io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.7.0"
```

Comment: Which version of swagger are you using?

Comment: If possible, use latest version, it will reduce some warning...If any specific error, you can write

Comment: @SkyWalker  I don't understand what the Swagger version has got to do with it. This has to do with Eclipse warnings, right? Swagger is configured through Gradle. I think IntelliJ users are not seeing the same issue.

Comment: Some warning can be found in intelliJ. is there any error? or you are getting just warning

Comment: @SkyWalker  No IntelliJ users are not seeing any issues on this file / project.  But also, I noticed that a `application.yml` file has no errors in Eclipse (or IntelliJ). So this is some cross-over between Swagger, Eclipse and Gradle?

Comment: So, it is occured in your PC, but others teammates are OK?

Comment: @SkyWalker Actually, I'm the only Eclipse user with this project code (or similar) checked out. Sorry that's awkward. I'll ask around.

Comment: If you have any error, let me know. Otherwise ignore it

Comment: @SkyWalker  Well, that was the point of my question. I want to ignore it, but it's a lot of noise in the "Problems" window of Eclipse, that's all.

Comment: plz run the following answers 2 command

Answer (score 0):

Go to your build.gradle file

Add

> ```
> apply plugin: 'eclipse'
> ```

Then run the command

```
gradle cleanEclipse eclipse

gradle clean build install
```

Comment: Sorry. No difference at all.

Comment: hmm..on that case, you can check through google of all warning one by one

Answer (score 0):

This seems rather odd, and if someone has a better explanation, I'll gladly accept that, but the problem seems to have "fixed itself".

The changes that I made, in sequence, which arrived at fixing are:

- Attempted the gradle changes described in `SkyWalker`'s answer **- Still warnings**
- `Right Click -> Configure -> Convert to Gradle (STS) Project` (Because applying "Eclipse plugin" from Gradle had the effect of undoing this) **- Still warnings**
- Made edits & changes to `swagger.yml` from an editor external to Eclipse **- Still warnings** after refresh (F5)
- Made edits to `swagger.yml` from within Eclipse **- Warnings disappeared upon saving**

I don't get it. I just post it here for posterity.